# Python: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, keyword

In a Python script I call a function from `rpy2`, but I get this error:

```
#using an R module 
res = DirichletReg.ddirichlet(np.asarray(my_values),alphas,
                              log=False, sum.up=False) 
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

What exactly went wrong here?

Comment: Regarding your update:  Many syntax errors come with a caret `^` pointing at the token that caused the parse error, others (including this one) don't.  In any case, pay attention to the error message, and [google the error messgae](http://www.google.com/search?q=Python+"keyword+can't+be+an+expression") if necessary.  In this case, the first hits should have cleared up things.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Googling the error message brings you to this page now.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`sum.up` is not a valid keyword argument name.  Keyword arguments must be valid identifiers.  You should look in the documentation of the library you are using how this argument *really* is called – maybe `sum_up`?

Comment: Yes, that was it. I forgot that when dealing with R functions, all the dots needs to be translated into underscores. So `sum_up` did the trick. :)

Comment: Just had the same syntax error because I was using an argument name "my-argument-name". Your answer helped me to find out that renaming it to "my_argument_name" can resolve the error.

Answer (score 24):

I guess many of us who came to this page have a problem with **Scikit Learn,** one way to solve it is to create a dictionary with parameters and pass it to the model:

```
params = {'C': 1e9, 'gamma': 1e-07}
cls = SVC(**params)
```

Comment: Why not `cls = SVC(C=1e9, gamma=1e-07)`?

Comment: @MattS it works, but sometimes you store parameters in a dictionary, therefore, you need to "unpack" it.

Comment: Using kwargs to the rescue! I love this technique for dynamic parameter names (: https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Answer (score 8):

It's python source parser failure on `sum.up=False` named argument as sum.up is not valid argument name (you can't use dots -- only alphanumerics and underscores in argument names).

Answer (score 7):

Using the Elastic search DSL API, you may hit the same error with

```
s = Search(using=client, index="my-index") \
    .query("match", category.keyword="Musician")
```

You can solve it by doing:

```
s = Search(using=client, index="my-index") \
    .query({"match": {"category.keyword":"Musician/Band"}})
```

Answer (score 3):

I just got that problem when converting from `%` formatting to `.format()`.

Previous code:

```
"SET !TIMEOUT_STEP %{USER_TIMEOUT_STEP}d" % {'USER_TIMEOUT_STEP' = 3}
```

Problematic syntax:

```
"SET !TIMEOUT_STEP {USER_TIMEOUT_STEP}".format('USER_TIMEOUT_STEP' = 3)
```

The problem is that `format` is a function that needs parameters. They cannot be strings.
That is one of worst python error messages I've ever seen.

Corrected code:

```
"SET !TIMEOUT_STEP {USER_TIMEOUT_STEP}".format(USER_TIMEOUT_STEP = 3)
```

Comment: Not sure if you answered OP's question but you answered the question I had regarding the format function needing parameters, not strings.