# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression in GAEpython

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

```
def email_status(self, mail_ref):
        mails_storage = EmailsStorage().Key(urlsafe=mail_ref)
        maillog = EmailLogs.query(EmailLogs.email_key=mails_storage)
        return mails_storage.get(), mails_log
```

it says SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression. I am new to GAEpython and couldnt figure out what is wrong.

Traceback
[image]

Comment: Were you going to include the traceback?

Comment: Please don't insert text (the traceback) as images in SO...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633421/python-syntaxerror-keyword-cant-be-an-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query you have `=` instead of `==`, you need

```
    maillog = EmailLogs.query(EmailLogs.email_key == mails_storage)
```

instead of

```
    maillog = EmailLogs.query(EmailLogs.email_key=mails_storage)
```