# Python: SyntaxError using bitwise function

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I am trying to create a basic bitwise function that filters out a certain subset of my data for me.

```
>>>heads=fits.open('datafile.fits')
>>>data=heads[1].data
```

Now, I need to mask out data points that are in a certain column and which are set to bit 0.

```
>>>ind=np.where(data['COLUMN_NAME'] & np.power(2,9) = 0)
```

However, this input throws the error

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword cant be an expression
```

The error does not give the normal ^ which shows where the error is, so I'm not sure which part of my input python is having an issue with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633421/python-syntaxerror-keyword-cant-be-an-expression)

Comment: The question of `==` and `=` has been asked tons and tons of times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

equal comparsion is `==`:

```
ind=np.where(data['COLUMN_NAME'] & (2**9) == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you use '=' (assignment) instead of '==' (equality) in the call to 'where'?