# How to run for loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a coursera course and want to create various dataframe using for loop, the idea is to create a list and then add each df into the list. However, below come back with error:

```
File "<ipython-input-10-2863e455a5c5>", line 7
    array.append(county_df.where(county_df['STNAME']=state))
                                ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

---

```
census_df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
county_df=census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50]
county_df.head()
county_df['STNAME'].unique()
list = []
print type(list)
for state in county_df['STNAME'].unique():
    array.append(county_df.where(county_df['STNAME']=state))

print (list)
```

Comment: In your code `array` shouldn't be list?

Comment: Avoid shadowing reserved words like `list`.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11633421/1240268

Answer (score 1):

In pandas we usually do this ..

```
l=[]

for _, df1 in county_df.groupby('STNAME'):
    l.append(df1)
```

You code error

`county_df['STNAME']=state)`

should be

`county_df['STNAME']==state)`

And base on my understanding

```
county_df.loc[county_df['STNAME']==state,:]
```

Comment: can also do with a list comprehension :)

Comment: This doesn't explain the `keyword can't be an expression` hmmm

Comment: Ah, gotcha, so `county_df['STNAME']` is trying to be passed as a keyword argument to `.where`

Answer (score 0):

I always convert my Pandas DataFrame to list by:

```
my_dataframe.values.tolist()
```