# SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression Python 3.6.3

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to learn Python, upon following an exercise I get the following error:
*SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression* on the following line:

```
boton = Button(ventanita.text="Evento",command=parpadeo)
```

No idea what that means, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example. We can't debug your code if there's no code to see.

Comment: `ventanita.text` the dot is very suspicious, it is supposed to be a keyword argument, and the keyword cannot have a dot AFAIK.

Comment: Did you mean `Button(ventanita,text=...)`?

Comment: this is all my code:
from tkinter import *
import time

def parpadeo():
    ventanita.iconify()
    time.sleep(3)
    ventanita.deiconify()


ventanita = Tk()
boton = Button(ventanita.text="Evento",command=parpadeo)
boton.pack()
ventanita.mainloop()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633421/python-syntaxerror-keyword-cant-be-an-expression)

Answer (score 0):

A keyword argument is when you pass the argument to a function like this:

```
print_text(text='hello')
```

Then, `text` is called the keyword and `'hello'` is the argument. In the code you show, you pass an argument `"Evento"` this way, but the keyword `ventanita.text` is not correct, as it is an expression (having the dot) and not a valid keyword. So, you need to check the documentation of the `Button` function and see what is the correct keyword (probably just `text`).

Comment: thanks, it works now. Sorry for the non-formatted code in the comment

Answer (score 0):

You are improperly passing parameters.  The `ventanita.text` is not correct. it should be a single identifier and not one that provides any structure.